# LESS (noun): "Hundreds of soldiers arrive, but less [of them] remain(s)"

Tags: verb-agreement

> **LESS** (*noun*) "a smaller amount or quantity":
>
> *Hundreds of soldiers arrived, but **less** of them remained*.
>
> https://www.wordreference.com/definition/least

What would be the correct agreement for the verb remain in the following two sentences then?

1. *Hundreds of soldiers arrive every day, but **less** of them remain(**s**).*
2. *Hundreds of soldiers arrive every day, but **less** remain(**s**).*

Comment: Just a note, you should use *fewer* when describing something countable (like soldiers), and *less* when describing something uncountable (like a liquid). You might have fewer soldiers or less water, but not less soldiers or fewer water.

Comment: In this context **few** remain. There are many duplicates about less/fewer but I can't find one with less/few. "Hundreds of soldiers arrived, but few remain."

Comment: @WeatherVane: But *fewer* than *hundreds of soldiers* might still be *many,* not *few.* There is nothing wrong with *fewer* here.

Comment: @PeterShor true: *how many* remain is relevant. If 99 remain, they are not 'few', but if 3 remain they are. It's an option.

Comment: @WeatherVane That's referring to the determiner/adjective meaning, or the idioms (such as _no less than_) but apparently not to the noun

Comment: @GJC: Why not to the noun? Because it doesn't explicitly say so in the dictionary? That's not a very convincing argument.

Comment: @PeterShor For OED **hundreds** here is _"a large **amount**"_ ,  and less is used for amounts such as _less than 5 bucks_ https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/hundred

Comment: I don't care about the ***fewer / less*** canard. But I think that example usage *Hundreds of soldiers arrived, but less of them remained* is *extremely* non-idiomatic. I'd be okay with *(**facetious**)* *...but **rather** less of them remained* (jocular "understatement", equivalent to *...but **very few** of them remained*). But as presented, it just looks weird to me.

Comment: @FumbleFingers https://i.imgur.com/MkF71HS.jpg

Comment: @GJC: That's odd. I know there could be contexts where "you" is *singular* (as in *I'd rather see **less of you***), which obviously might skew NGram results comparing ***less of you,fewer of you***. But it sticks out a mile that "fewer" is extremely uncommon there. And although *fewer of **them*** has totally swamped *less of them* in recent decades, that (to me, "non-intuitive") usage shift is nowhere near so marked with *less / fewer of **us***. Whatever - I still don't really care about the distinction, but apparently it's more of a ***new*** "rule" (in the observance), not "Victorian".

Comment: @FumbleFingers _"fewer" is extremely uncommon there_ Could you elaborate?

Comment: @GJC: There wasn't room to actually include a link to my ***less of you,fewer of you*** NGram, but since you'd obviously done one for ***less of them,fewer of them*** I assumed you could see where I was going with it. The usage shift is much less with ***us*** than ***them***,...

Comment: ... and it doesn't really exist at all with [***less/fewer of those***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=less+of+those%2Cfewer+of+those&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cless%20of%20those%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfewer%20of%20those%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cless%20of%20those%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfewer%20of%20those%3B%2Cc0) (where ***those*** or ***these*** are normally the plural alternatives to ***that, this***).

Comment: @FumbleFingers cf. _less/fewer of THESE_; why the discrepancy? https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=less+of+these%2Cfewer+of+these&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=50&case_insensitive=true

Comment: @GJC: I certainly can't explain it. Usually I'm pretty good at guessing in advance what NGrams is going to tell me. But I'd have taken it for granted that over the past century or two, ***fewer*** would be a massively declining usage compared to ***less*** in just about all contexts. But it turns out that although ***less*** is still much more common overall, it's actually losing traction compared to ***fewer***. The only explanation I can think of is there must be a ***lot*** of people these days paying attention in English classes because they're worried people will think they speak badly!

Comment: @FumbleFingers According to Garner's , _**Less** for singular nouns or units of measure: less tonic water, **one less golfer**, less than six ounces of epoxy_ https://books.google.es/books?id=2xv4CwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA560&dq=%22one%20less%20golfer%22&hl=es&pg=PA561#v=onepage&q=%22one%20less%20golfer%22&f=false

Comment: Have you made a search on "fewer less"?  If you do, you will see that yours is a common type of question for which there are useful answers.  For what it is worth, the traditional distinction between fewer and less is, in terms of actual usage, rapidly waning.

Comment: @GJC: That's Garner telling us the (current) "rule". It doesn't explain why this *particular* aspect of English seems to have shifted significantly towards actually making the distinction (which barely existed a century or two ago, but has become much more commonly observed over the past 50 years). I think this is an *unusual* usage shift, in that the current ***usage*** (not just "defined rules") now noticeably favours the more complex choice of phrasing. It was probably no more than a "stylistic choice" for the average Victorian.

Comment: **Few** refers to a small number of something countable "Few apples were worth eating"; "Few people saw the performance”  **Less** refers to a quantity of something uncountable, “There is less water/mud/ice in the river this year.” -- **Few** is to **many** as **less** is to **much**.

Answer (score 1):

In general "less" is singular and "few" is plural. This is because "less" is used uncountably and "few" is used countably.

**Examples**

*[Less is more](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Less+is+more)*  (singular)

*Fewer are expected for the meeting during Covid restrictions.* (plural)

**Answer**

Hundreds of soldiers arrive every day, but fewer remain.  (plural)

Comment: According to Garner's , _**Less** for singular nouns or units of measure: less tonic water, **one less golfer**, less than six ounces of epoxy_ https://books.google.es/books?id=2xv4CwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA560&dq=%22one%20less%20golfer%22&hl=es&pg=PA561#v=onepage&q=%22one%20less%20golfer%22&f=false

Comment: I mean, I observe this distinction, but it's pretty plain that many native speakers of standard English do not, and not only in especially casual contexts.

Comment: The stipulation is prescriptive. "That's one less problem" in conversation is standard, and here 'Hundreds of soldiers arrived. Less of them remained.' would be acceptable in print. 'Fewer' here is getting to sound rarefied.